# How to extend JHipster JDL

Tags: jhipster

We would like to extend JDL to represent some additional GUI aspects in the generated frontend. E.g.:

- show additional attributes from joined entities in the table
- show custom defined attribute instead of entity ID in dropdowns
- show detail list in parent entity form
- etc.

Is there any way to extend JDL and use it in some custom blueprint? Or should we use some different approach?

Comment: Extending the JDL currently means forking it. So, I would rather suggest you to propose contributing these changes to JHipster project.

Comment: Thank you @Gaël Marziou! We are thinking about it right now. Is there JHipster v8 roadmap? How can we join to the development process?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't yet a v8 roadmap but new features can be added to v7 as long as they don't introduce breaking changes. I would recommend that you open separate issues per feature request to open discussion rather than a single issue with many improvements.

Answer (score 1):

In relation to the second item, there is a feature in the JDL relationship definition which helps:

```
relationship (OneToMany | ManyToOne | OneToOne | ManyToMany) {
  <from entity>[{<relationship name>[(<display field>)]}] to <to entity>[{<relationship name>[(<display field>)]}]+
}
```

If you define one "display field" for the relationship end, JH will generate a drop-down using that field instead of the "id".

In relation to the third item, I am also interested in that feature. So, please let us know if you find a solution.